# The Device that up links e ticket direct to luggage display

Tags: usd633718

This patent is the only luggage technology that up links the e ticket from a phone or computer direct to luggage thus it replaces the paper tag for all luggage carry on backpacks in the wolrd

Comment: Hi Gerard, welcome to Ask Patents. Unfortunately commentary on patents like this isn't a great fit for [our Q&A format](/tour), because it's impossible to give a succinct and objective answer to. If you have a specific question about this patent, feel free to post that anew using the "Ask Question" button at the top of the page, but please be sure that it conforms to our [help/on-topic] to make sure we'll be able to help you.